# Rcpp Error with Xcode 5.0 and OSX 10.8.5 and R 3.0.2

Tags: xcode, r, macos, rcpp

I'm just trying to get Rcpp up and running on my Mac, but am struggling.  I've installed the Command Line Tools.  I've installed the Rcpp and inline packages.  I try to run the following script in R, and get the following error.

```
fx <- cxxfunction(signature( x = "numeric" ),

  'NumericVector xx(x);

  return wrap( std::accumulate( xx.begin(), xx.end(), 0.0));',

  plugin = "Rcpp",verbose=TRUE)


Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! /bin/sh: llvm-g++-4.2: command not found
make: *** [file2e731b1c0ff8.o] Error 127
```

I realize this is very similar to a posted question.  But I'd appreciate a reference to more details on where to find the makevars file.

Thanks.

Comment: The same question was asked and answered already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I [alluded to in this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19505397/143305), you must correct the values hard-coded in the R binary provided by CRAN which was built with the **old** XCode which still had the g++-based compiler. You have (at least) three choices:

1. Edit `etc/Makeconf` (below R's install directory) directly to correct `CC` and `CXX` to `clang` and `clang++`.
2. Alternatively, create or edit `~/.R/Makevars` similarly.
3. Create environment variables `CC` and `CXX` with these loadings.

The long and short of it is that `CC` and `CXX` have hard-coded values from R's compile-time which no longer correspond the values on your system (using XCode 5).  Eventually, R will catch up and this adjustment will be unnecessary.

The R Installation and Administration manual has more to say about which variables and which values you should use on a given architecture.

Comment: Thanks, I chose option 1, and it seems like everything is ok.  Now to start on learning to use Rcpp!

Comment: Sure thing -- and do come over to the rcpp-devel list too for questions.  Oh, and please feel free to 'accept' the answer by clicking on the tick mark symbol.

Answer (score 3):

Since g++ is no longer included in Xcode 5, you will have to re-direct the pointers to clang.
Based on @Romain Francois' answer from [Error when with Xcode 5.0 and Rcpp (Command Line Tools ARE installed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503995/error-when-with-xcode-5-0-and-rcpp-command-line-tools-are-installed?rq=1), you will have to create your own Makevars file in the ~/.R/ directory. Example content of Makevars would contain:

```
CC=clang
CXX=clang++
CFLAGS="-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion"
CXXFLAGS="-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion"
FLIBS=-lgfortran
```

Comment: Just to elaborate, neither the directory nor the file exist by default; you have to create both yourself.