# Trying to run Rcpp in R but unable to create makevars file

Tags: xcode, r, rcpp

There have previous discussions regarding the compiler in XCode and its relation to the Rcpp package. For instance, here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19550947/1786009 
It seems that the answer is to create a Makevars file in the directory ~/.R/Makevars
My question is simple, how do I find where the .R directory is?

Comment: By default, the folder won't exist. In a terminal, run `mkdir ~/.R` and then edit the file `~/.R/Makevars` to add the `CC` and `CXX` variables. It will be located in your home directory (this is what `~` stands for), probably `/Users/login` where "login" is your username.

Comment: If you install R using macports (homebrew might work too), you don't have to worry about this, since R and all packages are then automatically compiled from source with the available compilers.

Comment: But macports and homebrew are not officially supported. I would *strongly* recommend to follow Simon's advice and the counsel on the r-sig-mac list.

Comment: I created a folder in the terminal a like josilber said and I created the makevars using the cat command in R. It worked. I wish I could declare this question answered, but there were no answers, only comments. Thanks Dirk for the Rcpp package, I look forward to using it. Thanks everyone for taking the time what may seem to you like a very naive question. It is hard to learn these things starting from zero ;)