# Failed to install command line tools on OSX Mavericks

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, osx-mavericks

I tried to install the command line tools on Mavericks following the steps in this very useful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216865/how-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks)

```
> xcode-select --install
```

but after a few short seconds I get the message

[image]

This seems wrong. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

---

Whenever I navigate to the page that @Nikos M. is suggesting

[image]

I get this message

[image]

---

I followed @Rich's suggestion and I was able to download the package and install it which I wasn't able to do before, but I've found that I still don't have access to a lot of the commands that I should like `arp` or `diskutil` just to name two that I've encountered recently.

Comment: Note that Mavericks already comes with shims for the command line tools that point to the tools already inside Xcode. This is equivalent to running "xcrun COMMAND". So you may not need to install them separately at all, depending on your needs.

Comment: What do you mean by "I no longer have terminal on my computer"? /Applications/Terminal.app is part of OS X.

Comment: @MartinR I mean when I go to finder and search terminal nothing comes up. And I just checked in Applications for Terminal.app and thats not there either.

Comment: Correction: It is /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app.

Comment: It's there now and I clicked on it and now it appears when I search in finder. But I swear it was not doing this before.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Install them from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-). You must be a registered developer.

Other solution is: in xcode click Xcode>Open Developer Tool>More Developer Tools

This should then take you to a link which will require a developer Apple ID sign in. From there, you'll be redirected after authenticating to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ where you can manually download and install the Command Line Tools.

Comment: this worked for me.  also you don't have to install Xcode with Mavericks -- see this http://www.computersnyou.com/2025/

Comment: A note to the comment by @nikos-m. You don't need to be a paying developer to download, a registered developer is enough.

Comment: @dploeger You are wrong. I've just checked out that command tools 7.3.1 is available only for paid developers. This is the real apple way: We have a bug? We can fix it for paid developers. Ahaha!

Answer (score 12):

The tools are still free, but xcode-select --install is no longer supported.

To install the latest command-line developer tools from https://developer.apple.com,

1. Applications -> App Store -> Search -> XCode -> Install ... install
   XCode if you don't have it.
2. Open XCode and close any pop-ups
3. Go to the Xcode menu > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools... this opens the correct website.
4. Find the newest version, download the dmg and install the package.  The filename you're looking for is similar to "Command Line Tools (OS X 10.9).pkg"

Comment: "xcode-select --install" is supported once again with Yosemite.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem for months and finally found the solution.

The problem was: I had installed it before and removed it manually.
(I had problems with the bundled git. It was not the smartest move to do this.)

What i didn't remove were the files

```
/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables.bom
/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables.plist
```

Delete them, run `xcode-select --install` -> no error anymore

At least it worked for me. Hope it is helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I get that "Your Session has Expired" message when I try to download from within the Chrome browser. If I navigate to the site with Safari and sign in with my developer credentials then the Command Line Tools dmg downloads without a problem. I do not have a paid developer account either, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can download your Command Line Tools from daw.apple.com, but try it from Safari instead of Chrome.

I tried it with Chrome for a few hours and apple would not recognize my id/password (it is the same as your AppleID).  It required me to change my password after each third try, which was challenging because it would not let you use any password you've used in the last three years.

Signing in via Safari gave me no problems.

The file you are going to look for is Command Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) for Xcode - Late October

If your terminal still says you need to install command line tools, it may be an issue with gcc-4.2.  I was able to confirm that was the issue by following my terminal message after I ran "bundle install" on my rails app.  If this is your issue, you will do the following follow Housen's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503995/error-when-with-xcode-5-0-and-rcpp-command-line-tools-are-installed).  Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I spent the day trying to solve this problem. I believe the error messages are just confused about installing Xcode. The real problem I had  was a need to update gcc compiler. This happened to me because I skipped Mountain Lion, where that occurred. [This blog post](http://new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2013/10/24/3-quick-tips-for-coding-with-os-x-10-9-mavericks) was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by open XCode UI, then adding my apple account
Xcode -> Preference -> Add my APPLE ID account

Then repeat the **xcode-select --install**

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the command line tools following 
[Error Message "Xcode alone is not sufficient on Sierra"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460085/error-message-xcode-alone-is-not-sufficient-on-sierra/47605660#47605660)

brew seems checks if the command line tools installed in this path:

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
My case is: I tried to install brew on my new mac. After I installed Xcode, there was nothing in the above path but the command line tools were somehow installed to another location. (xcode-select -p tell me it was /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer)
The way in stackoverflow can install the command line tools to

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
Now I got brew working. But I am not sure if it is the best solution as there should be two copies of command line tools on my machine using this method.