# Command Line Tools on OSX 10.9: Installed, but can't show up?

Tags: xcode, macos, bash, osx-mavericks, command-line-tool

I am trying to install CLT on OSX 10.9 Mavericks.

Before I ask, I referred to these questons:

[Failed to install command line tools on OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691701/failed-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks)

[Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-command-line-tools)

I installed XCode 5 via the App Store, with the latest version.

Then, as mentioned in all kinds of tutorials, I typed "xcode-select --install" in the bash, however, there weren't any window telling me to install the CLI, but these outputs:

```
$ xcode-select --install
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

I tried to run `"/System/Library/CoreServices/Install\ Command\ Line\ Developer\ Tools.app"` manually, but nothing showed up.

I opened the package, and tried

```
"sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Install\ Command\ Line\ Developer\ Tools.app/Contents/MacOS/Install\ Command\ Line\ Developer\ Tools "
```

And failed like this:

```
"2013-11-01 19:48:45.060 Install Command Line Developer Tools[42474:507] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x6207, name = 'com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes."
```

I enabled root account and try to run it under root, same output.

Unknown of what that means, I tried `"--pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI"`

It seems that CLI is not working, the outputs are:

```
"No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'."
```

I went to Apple 's site, downloaded and installed this file:

```
command_line_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode__late_october_2013.dmg
```

Everything goes smoothly, no error reported during the installation.

However, when I try to find the CLI in XCode, it is not there.

Another time `"--pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI", still "No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.".`

Now I am completely puzzled...how can I install this CLI?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting to show up in XCode?

Comment: I am expecting CLI would show up in "downloads", which is not.

Comment: The Xcode CLI tools are no longer downloaded through Xcode, so they don't show up in its Downloads manager. I suspect you've already installed them and you just haven't realized it! Try running `cc` from a terminal.

Comment: The result is "i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files". That means OK? Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't look right - cc should be clang on current versions of Xcode.

Comment: It could be OK... If I type `cc` I get a `clang` message, and if I type `gcc` I get the `livm-gcc-4.2` message.

Comment: Both "gcc" and "cc" would return "i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files" on my machine... is that right?

Comment: I get clang error no input files. what does that mean?  Ive run the XcodeCLT.pkg from late october, it went through the motions but I can't find the Xcode CLT.  What happened?

Comment: The CLI tools dmg is located in the following folder when you download it from within Xcode `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads` is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I checked, it's not there...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have updated to the most recent version of Mavericks, then reboot. Run `xcode-select --install` again. Otherwise, uninstall XCode and reinstall again from App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I called `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and then `xcode-select --install`. 
sw_vers:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.2
BuildVersion:   19C57
```