# Error Message "Xcode alone is not sufficient on Sierra"

Tags: ruby, xcode, python-3.x, homebrew, command-line-tool

I'd like to install openCV to vectorize image, but there's a series error message regarding Xcode and Ruby.

First, I use terminal to install openCV, `brew install opencv`.

Then, I got error message indicating that the system doesn't like my ruby version.

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:12:in `<main>': 
Homebrew must be run under Ruby 2.3! You're running 2.0.0. (RuntimeError)
```

So, I want to upgrade my ruby. I followed several update strategy from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite) post. First ruby upgrade trial: `brew link --overwrite ruby` & `brew unlink ruby && brew link ruby` and get

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby
```

Then second ruby upgrade trial: `brew upgrade ruby` and see the following error message.

```
Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Sierra.
Install the Command Line Tools:
xcode-select --install
```

This error message means I need to install Xcode which I already install. So, I check my Xcode status with `code-select -p` and get `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` which means I am fine.

I saw a [comment](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/) regarding where you install python could be a big issue. Quote from the source:

> If you see `/usr/local/bin/python3` then you are correctly using the Homebrew version of Python. If the output is instead `/usr/bin/python3` then you are incorrectly using the system version of Python.

I check `which python3` and get

```
/Users/******/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Could this be the problem? How can I change system version to local?

Comment: The error says “please run this command to install command line tools since just having Xcode isn’t enough.” Did you run that command?

Comment: Like @SamiKuhmonen mentioned, you need to actually have installed the command line tools. Even if you install (or any time you upgrade) Xcode you have to install the tools. There is a way to do it by opening Xcode and using the menus but the easiest is to just run the command the error mentions.

Comment: Just a note: installing command line tools doesn't resolve this problem for me. I have command line tools installed, but still get the error "Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Sierra." (using homebrew python 2.7.14)

Comment: I met the same error, and the Xcode is also installed, but fixed this problem by run "xcode-select --install" and install the command line tool again.

Comment: running `xcode-select --install` solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Let me explain this myself so people won't make the same mistakes.

When I saw the last line of the error message

```
Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Sierra.
Install the Command Line Tools:
xcode-select --install
```

My thought was: I already have Xcode why the system ask me to "reinstall" it. However, thanks for @SamiKuhmonen @ Beartech @patrick kuang suggestion, I search a [page](https://courses.growthschool.com/courses/path-to-rails-developer/lectures/744354) (in Mandarin). `xcode-select --install` does not reinstall the whole Xcode. It means install some missing command line tools which is required by installing Ruby.

Comment: I don't know but I think something is wrong with Mac OS(10.14) distribution. Because, when I try to install X-Code command Line tools using the **command, it fails all the time**. I had  to **manually download the Command Line Tools package from Apple Website as shown in the answer below.** I'm not saying this answer is wrong, but I felt sharing my experience. :) Hope this helps future answer seekers.

Answer (score 23):

Trying to install k8s package via `brew` , I just got the same issue a while ago saying in the terminal :

> Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Sierra.
>
> Install the Command
>
> Line Tools:   xcode-select --install

You  need to  download `*.dmg` file; named **Command Line Tools (macOS x.x.x) for XCode N** . Search on it here : https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ . You must have developer account.
[image]

Then, congrats!

## update for 2019

macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Use Xcode10.2 for macOS 10.14

[image]

Comment: Screenshot is very helpful - have to use this if the command line xcode-select --install doesn't work

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue in my Macbook Pro on Sierra. Apart from updating Xcode from the App Store, I also installed the command line utilities using the `xcode-select --install` command.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After the update steps, `brew` commands started working fine. I also updating my OS during this time.

Comment: I guess if you `ssh`ed to your mac you wont see it

Answer (score 7):

I got the same message despite having Xcode and the command line tools already being [installed a long time ago](https://wiert.me/2016/11/16/xcode-select-install-required-for-os-x-10-9-xcode-command-line-tools-like-zlib-devel/) and updated numerous times.

I think it is the Apple way of telling you that Xcode command line tools need to be updated, as the App Store showed me the below:

[image: Command Line Tools (mac OS Sierra version 10.12) for Xcode 9.1]

After executing the `xcode-select --install` command, the update disappears from the App Store, which means they are exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I checked my Xcode update status as well. From both terminal and in "App store", it seems that there is nothing I need to update.

Comment: @Ying that's the thing: installing the update from the App Store does the same as running the command `xcode-select --install`, which means that after running the command, you will not see the update in the App Store any more.

Comment: @Jeron I didn't mention clearly in my question. I do check in the App Store and I didn't see anything I need to update there. That's why I am confused and didn't run `xcode-select --install`. However, `xcode-select --install` is the correct way to solve my issue.

Comment: @Ying you are right: the App Store sometimes forgets to refresh itself. I always do a manual refresh in it (with the `Command-R` key combination).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I installed 'Command Line Tools for XCode' (choose appropriate version) from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and restarted my terminal. Issue resolved :)

Comment: This basically repeats the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605660/466862